# CSS on condition

Tags: html, css

Does CSS support conditions? I mean that there is hover, so when mouse is on it, element style changes.
I have class `".menu_top_line"` with `display:none`, can I change it to `"display:block"`, when mouse is on other element?
Like:

```
nav ul li:hover
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    // other block.display:block
}
```

Comment: The *only* "conditions" CSS has are [selectors and selector precedence](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html). The attributes *always* apply to the *subject* in the selector.

Comment: You can do that only if the 'other element' is a parent of .menu_top_line

Comment: Yes. It is. Thank you for right "word". I think of element>element div>p Selects all <p> elements where the parent is a <div> element

Comment: Doesn't need to be a parent. It can be a descendant, a later sibling or a descendant of a later sibling. (With level 3 CSS selectors)

Comment: nav ul li:hover > .menu_top_line
{
 display:block;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to reference another element from inside a ruleset.

If you can write a selector that matches the element you want to manipulate which also references the element you want to hover, then you can just apply the `:hover` to that element in the selector.

```
nav ul li:hover > .menu_top_line {
    display: block;
}
```

Otherwise you need JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for a **child** element, **descendent** or an **immediately next sibling**.

You can use (`>`)-operator to select any immediate child element `space( )` for descendent element and (`+`)-operator for an immediately next sibling element.

Let me show you the **sibling selection** similar to the answer given by @Quentin i.e. *for child selection only*.-

```
nav ul li:hover + .menu_top_line {
    display: block;
}
```

this will address those elements with class `menu_top_line` that follows a `li` that is child of a `ul` that is child of a `nav`-element.

So there are 3 means to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but only if the element you are targeting the "mouse is over some other element" condition to is some child (or grandchild) of the element you're holding the mouse over.

```
ul li a {
    /* normal */
}
ul:hover li a {
    /* a's style when the mouse is over the ul */
}
```